# Calculate the r-squared value for a random network in R

Tags: r, igraph, pearson-correlation

I created a set of random networks in R using the erdos-renyi algorithm. However, I cannot find a function to calculate the R-squared (Pearson correlation coefficient) value of the graph. Fro example, if I use the function erdos renyi game in the igraph package to make my network

```
erdos.renyi.game(281, 447, type = "gnm",m = 465, directed = FALSE)
```

How would I be able to calculate the R-squared value for this?

Comment: Please take some time to look at the meaning and usage of the R-square

Comment: The idea of R-squared is as a proportion of variance explained.  I assume you have data that is interval.  These are the data points. You also need a model that predicts your data. This is the model.  You also need a prediction of the data made without using your model, commonly called the average.  Take the square of the data points minus the average.  Sum that.  This the denominator. Take the square of the modeled points minus the average. Sum that. This the numerator.  Divide. That's your R-Square.

Comment: presuming you want the pearson correlation (aka _r_ or _rho_) and _not_ the coefficient of determination (aka R-squared), you can use the `gcor` function from the `sna` package. If you want to test the significance of the correlation, use `qaptest` from `sna`.

Comment: but i’m assuming here—please clarify your question.

Comment: @paqmo Wow.. I have always thought that the Pearson correlation coefficient and the coefficient of determination is the same. I needed a function to get the R-squared value. If you could put it up as a answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @Charles well, they are related, since r-squared is the squared value of r -- but the context matters. R squared is the squared correlation between the observed and predicted values of a linear model. In this case, it looks like you are trying to determine the bivariate correlation of two graphs, e.g., the pearson correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)
library(intergraph)
library(sna)

# create the graphs
gs <- replicate(2,  
                sample_gnm(281, 447,m = 465, directed = FALSE),
                simplify = F) 
# sample_gnm is preferred to erdos.renyi.game now

# turn them into network objects
nets <- lapply(gs, asNetwork)
```

Now use `gcor` to get the correlation and `qaptest` to test the significance.

```
gcor(nets, g1 = 1, g2 =2)
[1] 0.003537025
qaptest(nets, gcor, g1 = 1, g2 = 2)

QAP Test Results

Estimated p-values:
    p(f(perm) >= f(d)): 0.17 
p(f(perm) <= f(d)): 0.834
```